# no wifi Adapter found in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, wireless

Suddenly my wifi is not working and I have tried almost everything but nothing is working for me . Here are some commands I have already tried .

1)lspci | grep Network
No result is showing and after echo $? it shows 1 .

2. I tried this method -

   ```
   sudo apt install build-essential git dkms
   git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
   cd rtl8821ce
   sudo ./dkms-install.sh
   sudo modprobe 8821ce
   reboot
   ```

3)There is nothing in Additional Drivers

4)lshw -C net  *-network

```
    description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 0c
       serial: 84:7b:eb:2a:2c:a9
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.1.23 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7000000-f7000fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
work
```

5. sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces

   // interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
   auto lo

   iface lo inet loopback

6)lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

7. lspci -nnk

   ```
    00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI [8086:1604] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI [1028:06c1]
    Kernel driver in use: bdw_uncore
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 [8086:1616] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell HD Graphics 5500 [1028:06c1]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
    00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller [8086:160c] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell Broadwell-U Audio Controller [1028:06c1]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
    00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller [8086:9cb1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller [1028:06c1]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 [8086:9cba] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller [1028:06c1]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
    00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller [8086:9ca0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller [1028:06c1]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
    00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:9c90] (rev e3)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
    00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 [8086:9c96] (rev e3)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
    00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:9c98] (rev e3)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
    00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller [8086:9ca6] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller [1028:06c1]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
    00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9cc5] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller [1028:06c1]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
    00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] [8086:9c83] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] [1028:06c1]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
    00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller [8086:9ca2] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller [1028:06c1]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
    07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1028:06c1]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
   ```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: @user535733 I am new to this so I was trying everything . Ca you help me what should I do ?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Your WiFi device isn't found anywhere. Either disabled in UEFI ("BIOS"), loose/disconnected or faulty. Not something you can fix from the OS.

Comment: @chili555 I have added the output .

Comment: @ChanganAuto are you certain this is the case ? How can I then enable it ?

Comment: I'm certain that isn't something you can fix from the OS. Not certain about which of the possibilities, of course. You should start by the easiest (UEFI) but this is also the least likely. Then re-seat the WiFi card if not soldered, of course. Replace it (again, if possible) if everything else fails.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanx a lot !